# C# Could not find a part of the path with Directory.GetDirectories

Tags: c#, copy

I'm trying to make an application that copies volume to a selected location in the computer.
The volume is an external hard disk that includes a copy of my previous computer C volume.

First of all, when I tried to copy the directories and the files I made an recursive function that gets the directories and the files and copy them to the new location, the recursive function gets the directories with Directory.GetDirectories function, after I get the sub directories I make the same function to get the sub directories of the sub directories and keeps doing that untill there are no directories to get, all works fine but when I tried to use the application on my volume I got an infiniate loop with "Application Data" folder, that means that the GetDirectories function found "Application Data" folder in the previous "Application Data" again and again.
In order to fix that I checked if the path does not include "Application Data\Application Data" and just the I used the GetDirectories function.
Maybe that solution caused the problem I'm going to ask about.

The problem is that when I use the function GetDirectories I get an exception: "Could not find a part of the path" but my code looks like this:

```
if(Directory.Exist(path))
{
    string[] subdirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
}
```

So how is that possible that the Exist function finds the folder but the GetDirectories function does not find it?
By the way, the application works properly on directories that are not part of windows system.
So what is the problem? And how can I solve it or how can I make copy application that will copy C volume?
Thanks a lot

Comment: There is an overload of [Directory.GetDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes a `SearchOptions` type. You can tell it to include all sub-directories, you don't need to use recursion here.

Comment: Recursion is needed if you don't have permission to read some of the files.  You will get exceptions and not be able to continue with out an exception handler.

Comment: @jdweng He's still using `Directory.GetDirectories()` in his recursive function - `"the recursive function gets the directories with Directory.GetDirectories function, after I get the sub directories I make the same function to get the sub directories of the sub directories"` which will throw the same exception anyway. Also, he's not reading files, he's reading directories. You're thinking of `Directory.GetFiles()`. Handling exceptions whilst enumerating the directories is a good idea anyway...

Comment: You will get the same issue with GetDirectories() and GetFile() when an exception occurs.  The code will stop on first exception.  You cannot use the option include all sub directories.  You must recursively parse each directory to continue past first exception.

Comment: That is a good question in this post. I am running into the issue where DirectoryInfo.GetFiles and maybe DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories are erroring out like that. I can go to Windows Explorer and see them. I checked the Path length is 68 characters for DIrectoryInfo Folder I am using. Seems like a bug in DirectoryInfo.GetFiles or GetDirectories. I don't think anyone really answered this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/827421):

> A service that runs under a LocalSystem account or under a local user
>   account can only access mapped drives that the service creates. Mapped
>   drives are stored for each logon session. If a service runs under a
>   LocalSystem account or under a local user account that does not create
>   certain mapped drives, the service cannot access these mapped drives.
>   Additionally, a service that runs under a local user account that
>   creates certain mapped drives also receives a new set of mapped drives
>   if you log off and then you log on again as the same local user.

There is a workaround but it not necessary, just use try-catch for those libs:

```
if(Directory.Exist(path))
{
    try
    {
        string[] subdirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Or, alternatively, use `Directory.GetDirectories` SearchOptions so you can disclude certin sub-directories.